# Word or phrase used to describe a person concerned with self preservation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, epithet-requests

If possible, it should also be casting a negative light on the person described. For instance:

> This assassin is __________ first, and opportunistic second. He primarily seeks to catch his target not only unaware, but in a situation where no one would be able to retaliate after the kill.

The assassin in this case is being described by a person who has nothing positive to say about him, so I would like to be able to fit that theme where appropriate.

Comment: Did you consider _self-preserving_?

Comment: @alwayslearning I did, but I was wondering if there was a better word or phrase for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use ***self-preserving*** as an adjective.

> This assassin is ***self-preserving*** first, and opportunistic
>   second. He primarily seeks to catch his target not only unawares, but
>   in a situation where no one would be able to retaliate after the kill.

dictionary.com:

> **[self-preservation](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-preserving)**
>   *noun*
>   **1.** preservation of oneself from harm or destruction.
>
> Related forms:
>   **self-preserving**, *adjective*
>
> In that moment Tito, with bloodless face and eyes dilated, had one of
>   the **self-preserving** inspirations that come in extremity.
>
> Romola
>   George Eliot
>
> Through all this bewilderment, **self-preserving** interest guides his
>   course.
>
> Oswald Langdon
>   Carson Jay Lee

Answer (score 0):

How about *survivor*?

From M-W:

> [*survivor*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/survivor): to
>   remain alive or in existence :  live on; to continue to function or
>   prosper

Your example:

> This assassin is a *survivor* first, and opportunistic second. He
>   primarily seeks to catch his target not only unaware, but in a
>   situation where no one would be able to retaliate after the kill.

Answer (score 0):

*Self-centered*: preoccupied with oneself and one's affairs.

> Engrossed in oneself and one's own affairs; selfish.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-centered

Comment: Come on, man. You've got over 7k reputation and yet you are a frequent visitor to the VLQ review queue. Please give a little bit more than just one-liners without any references.

Comment: @Helmar - I think at the time I wrote this answer I was a bit preoccupied with some personal affairs.  What's VLQ?  I don't visit it consciously.